# Is a global variable defined inside a Sinatra route shared between requests?

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

Say I've got:

```
get '/' do
 $random = Random.rand()
 response.body = $random
end
```

If I have thousands of requests per second coming to /, will the $random be shared and 'leak' outside the context or will it act like a 'local' variable to the get block?

I imagine if it was defined outside of the context of `get '/' do` it would indeed be shared but I wonder if there's a mechanic to $ in ruby that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This part of the Sinatra README about scope is always helpful to read](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Application/Class%20Scope) but if you only need the variable to persist for the request then I think there are 3 main ways I'd suggest going about this, and really the key is a [filter](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Filters)

#### A before block

```
before do
  @my_log = []
end

get "/" do
  @my_log << "hello"
  @my_log << "world"
  @my_log.inspect
end

get "/something-else" do
  @my_log << "is visible here too"
end

# => output is ["hello", "world"]
```

`@my_log` will go out of scope at the end of the request and be re-initialised at the beginning of the next one. It will be accessible by any route, so if for example you used `pass` to pass it on to another route that would be the only time the other blocks could see what had been set by the prior route block.

#### Using the settings helper

```
set :mylog, []
```

Then same as above, just replace `@my_log` with `settings.my_log`. Without the `before` block reinitialising it then the contents of `@my_log` would be persisted across requests.

#### Using the settings helper with something like Redis

```
# I always do this within a config block as then it's only initialised once
config do
  uri = URI.parse(ENV["URL_TO_REDIS"])
  set :redis, Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
end
```

Now the redis instance is available via `settings.redis`. No need to worry about variable scope (I'd use locals with it), just push straight to Redis. You get the best of both worlds then, but if you want you could do:

```
before do
  @my_log = []
end

get "/" do
  @my_log << "hello"
  @my_log << "world"
  "Hello, World"
end

after do
  settings.redis.set "some_key", @my_log
  settings.redis.expire "some_key", 600 # or whatever
end
```

Comment: I love this solution Sinatra + Redis italian mafias ;-)

Comment: In my case, this variable is only working with controllers, but no where else.

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper Not in helpers or `after` blocks, or views?

Comment: I am not a pro in Sinatra. I have a common function file in "app->utils" folder. I tried to use it in the controller and this file. It's working on the controller file, but not here. PS: How do you guys highlight code in comments?

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper Use backticks around code to highlight it. If you want, open a new question and I'll take a look (or I'm sure someone will) and put the link here.

Answer (score 3):

Other than some very specific exceptions (such as the regular expression match related globals) a global is shared with everything in the process - there is no scoping.

Comment: Is there a way to replicate a behavior of a global but only in the context of the do..end block?

Comment: The reason I thought of using it - it's very convenient to append data to as some functions and objects are created, as they're being created and used. So in a sense, sort of like a log. Instead of constantly returning the result to append it, I was hoping to just use the global but I guess not

Comment: @dsp_099 are you planning to store the information, or just use it later in the same request?

Comment: Just use it later in the same request. It's basically a log. I'll either want to output it or send it off to something like redis. I dont plan to keep that information for later requests to access