# How do I pass variables between routes without using sessions or haml in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, session-variables, erb

For example: when you want to return an error message to another page

Currenty I'm doing this like this

```
  get '/' do
    erb :home
  end


  get '/send/:user' do
    Process.detach(fork{ exec "ruby send.rb #{params[:user]} > output.txt"})   
    session['msg'] = "Process for the user #{params[:user]} iniciated, it will take a few minutes"
    redirect '/'
  end
```

and display the message like this in the .erb

```
<span style="margin:auto; text-align: center; padding:10px"><%=session['msg']%></span>
```

It has to be a better way that using sessions variables

using:

- ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
- sinatra (1.4.5)

Comment: Have you seen http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Error%20Handling?

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388263/is-a-global-variable-defined-inside-a-sinatra-route-shared-between-requests

Comment: yes, that's perfect when you want only show an error message and nothing else, in my case the message could or couldn't be an error and the message is only a small part of another .erb (html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be using [Sinatra Flash](https://github.com/SFEley/sinatra-flash) for the kind of mechanism you are after. Flash messages usually expire after one request so you don't need to manage them manually (They do use sessions in the background for storage):

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/flash'

enable :sessions

get '/' do
   erb :home
end

get '/send/:user' do
    Process.detach(fork{ exec "ruby send.rb #{params[:user]} > output.txt"})   
    flash[:msg] = "Process for the user #{params[:user]} initiated, it will take a few minutes"
    redirect '/'
end
```

In home.erb:

```
<span style="margin:auto; text-align: center; padding:10px"><%= flash[:msg] %></span>
```

Comment: much better than sessions, at least I don't need to empty the session variable every time, thanks